# customizing ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is it possible to customize `Home` button of action bar? 
I use this code for closing notification as home btn clicked, but nothing happens.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_adult1);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



}

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                notificationManager.cancel(notification_id);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

what can I do?

Comment: what does happen for Activity when i click on Home/Up button?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home)
        Log.d(TAG, "Home clicked");

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean showHomeAsUp)**

This method makes the icon and title in the action bar clickable so that “up” (ancestral) navigation can be provided.
This method will just make the icon and title pressable, but not actually add the functionality of navigating upwards. That has to be done by specifying the

> android:parentActivityName

(takes the parent activity class name) on the activity in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

Answer (score -2):

use

```
 @Override            
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
                super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
                mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

           if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    ///// write ur action code here
                }

}
```

Comment: I change it to ` @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     notificationManager.cancel(notification_id);
  }` but notification does not cancle.